# MS Excel: is there a simpler way to use an IF statement to check for matching data and output a date?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I have a list of lot IDs and dates in one tab ("Lot IDs"), raw data in two others, and data for presentation in the last tab ("Selected Data"). In the Selected Data tab there is an IF statement that checks to make sure the lot ID on a given line matches one of the lot IDs in the Lot Data tab and, if it is true, it outputs the date associated with the lot.

A snippet of my function, from the Selected Data tab:

```
=IF(B2=LEFT('Lot IDs'!$C$2,6),'Lot IDs'!$D$2,IF(B2=LEFT('Lot IDs'!$C$3,6),'Lot IDs'!$D$3,IF(B2=LEFT('1303 Lot IDs'!$C$4,6),'Lot IDs'!$D$4,"false/paste pattern here")))
```

where 
B column holds lot ID numbers
Lot IDs'!$C column holds lot ID numbers
Lot IDs'!$D column holds dates

This function is getting very long, over 30 repetitions.
Is there a way to generalize this function so I don't have to keep repeating the same pattern?

Comment: Can you share some sample data to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Without any data, the match() function may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH with wildcards:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Lot IDs'!$D:$D,MATCH(B2&"*",'Lot IDs'!$C$:$C,0)),"false/paste pattern here")
```